# Comments section being indented by mysterious CSS

Tags: css, comments

I use Disqus comments plugin for Wordpress, and the comments section is indented to the right like a blockquote is.

The code appearing in the front end post is:

```
 <div id="disqus_thread">
    <div id="dsq-content">
        <ul id="dsq-comments">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I cannot find any instance of disqus_thread or dsq using a search of the theme folder; not that searching inside file in Windows 7 isn't a complete pain in the arse.

Can you see why this is happening?  [Example post here](http://www.superlogical.net/society/greed/2011/06/beer-prices-in-perth/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `#dsq-content` div has a `margin-left` value of 30px. Add the following to the bottom of your WordPress theme's stylesheet to override it:

```
div#content div#disqus_thread div#dsq-content.clearfix{
    margin-left:0;
}
```

To edit a theme's stylesheet, go to the Appearance > Editor panel in the WordPress admin area.

Comment: I removed the .clearfix at the end of your CSS and it worked.  Where did you find the original CSS with a margin-left of 30px?

Comment: @Steve It's being pulled in from a stylesheet on disqus' server [here](http://mediacdn.disqus.com/uploads/styles/66/3968/superlogical.css?u=1302499188). (I found that out by using Chrome's Web Inspector: [screenshot.](https://img.skitch.com/20110628-cnd1b4jmg4ajfjt3hn6x6sw4xs.jpg))